# Largest Prime factor of a Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Take the function

$$ f(x) = 2x+1 $$

Is there a method to find when a specific prime, like $5$, is the largest prime factor of the function?

What I have done to try to solve this is by realizing that when,

$$ x = 10n+7 $$

For $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ then  $ 5 \mid f(x)$, but $ 5 $ isn't neccesarily the largest prime factor of $ f(x) $ for any $n$.

This then transforms our $ f(x) \rightarrow f(n) $ where

$$ f(n) = 20n + 15 $$

We can also see that when $ 5 $ is the largest prime factor of $f(n)$ then $3 \mid f(n)$ which means,

$$ 5(4n+3) = 3^a*5^b $$

For $ a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ b \in \mathbb{N} $. 
Simplifying,

$$ 4n+3 = 3^a*5^{b-1} $$

$ 5 $ is the largest prime factor of $ f(n) $ when $ n = \{ 0,3,6,18\} $, but there doesn't seem to be a direct pattern to when $ n $ is equal to some number and when $ 5 $ is the largest prime factor of $ f(n) $. This would also mean that $ n \subset \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Well I don't know such specific ways to determine the largest prime factor of an arithmetic progression because it was proven long ago by Dritchlet that there exist infinitely many primes in arithmetic progression a+nb where gcd(a,b)=1. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Saf_Swathi_Rosogolla Our function, now a function of $n$, would be represented now by $ f(n) = 20n+15 $, $ \gcd{(a,b)} \neq 1 $, for $ a = 15 $ and $ b = 20 $. Therefore we wouldn't neccesarily have a infinite number of primes formed from by the function.

Comment: I doubt that we can find the numbers in general, but in the case of $f(x)=2x+1$ it is easy since this represents just the odd numbers, therefore the prime factor $5$ is the largest prime factor , if and only if $f(x)$ is of the form $3^a\cdot 5^b$ with non-negative integer $a$ and positive integer $b$.

Comment: As for numbers whose largest prime factor is $5$, these would be the five-smooth numbers which are not three-smooth, https://oeis.org/A080193

Comment: Sieve of sundaram for the first, it's generalization and polynomial remainder theorem for the second.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee This sieve generates the primes, here we need $P$-smooth numbers (numbers with no prime factor larger than some given bound $P$)

Comment: you can sieve the a and b so they don't produce primes and get as many prime factors as you like @Peter

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee But we do not omit numbers with too large prime factors this way.

Comment: I highly doubt that we can find, lets say, all the $7$ - smooth numbers being of the form $24k+11$. We can of course set a limit and just enumerate all the smooth numbers and sieve out those satisfying our condition. In general, we won't have anything better.

Comment: that's simply a limit on a and b, @Peter

Comment: `apply(s->2*s[1]+1,select(r->r[2]!=r[3]&& #select(q->r[2]==q[1]||r[3]==q[1],c[1..vecmax(r)\4])==0,c=setbinop((a,b)->[2*a*b+a+b,a,b],[1..100])))` I've helped the likes of Dana Jacobsen before.

Comment: @JMoravitz: That's the same as saying "As for numbers whose largest prime factor is $5$, these would be the numbers whose largest prime factor is $\le 5$ and $> 3$." In other words, not very illuminating!

Comment: @TonyK and yet, it provided a link to the OEIS page which was my entire goal with the comment which would have linked to more information, articles, and papers if there were any particularly relevant ones.  That there aren't implies many better approaches than brute force.

Comment: @JMoravitz or that it's under a different approach, or never got published simply due to someone thinking it was trivial( I was once told I should get nominated for a fields medal, and had two people willing to help me write a paper, but I declined both, as I thought the result ( which I can't remember what it was now) was trivial).

Comment: @Dclrk f(n)=an+b with gcd(a,b)=d can be reduced to g(n)=cn+f where gcd(c,f)=1 where f(n)=dg(n) now note that g(n) can used the property of dritchlet and any factor p of g(n) also divides f(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sieve of sundaram logic ( also logic like polynomial remainder theorem) is $r=2a+1$ divides $2x+1$ when $x=rb+a$ for some value $b\in \mathbb{N}$ we then have to eliminate values that have higher factors. in the case of $5=2(2)+1$ ;$x$ needs to be 2 mod 5, but can't be 3 mod 7, 5 mod 11, 6 mod 13, 8 mod 17, 9 mod 19, 11 mod 23, or 14 mod 29 just for starters.  first two intersect in 17 mod 35, so that's out. This leaves 2,7,12,22,27,32 mod 35, which intersect the next one above at ( respectively) 247,357,82,302,27,137, mod 385, etc. this at least lets us clear up to a limit of $x$ values.  You can generalize to any multiplicative group as well, so for odd number values trying to sieve odd semiprimes, just use the values $m$ such that $6m+1$ or $6m+5$ can't be primes and sieve prime indexes after that.  You can limit $a,b$ to show if it has too high of factors.